# Difficulty using "count" for mysql queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I started with mysql and I had this problem

The problem is that I want to make a query between related trablas of a specific table where I have the gender of the people, be it woman or man.

This would be my code to make the query

```
SELECT c.Nom_carre as Preparatory, count(a.Gen_alum) as Gender
FROM alumno a, carrera c WHERE a.idCarrera=c.idCarrera
```

This code **count(a.Gen_alum)** shows me the total of people whether men or women.
I would like to know separately, how many men and how many women are?

Comment: You should either use conditianal aggregations (`COUNT(CASE WHEN a.Gen_alum = 'm' END) as total_m`) or `GROUP BY a.Gen_alum WITH ROLLUP`. But it's difficult/impossible to give you the correct answer as long as you don't clearly define the relations between the tables. Also note that it doesn't make sense to select any columns (like `c.Nom_carre`) that are not in the group by clause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should be use with `join`

```
SELECT c.Nom_carre as Preparatory, count(a.Gen_alum) as Gender
FROM alumno a
join carrera c on a.idCarrera=c.idCarrera
group by a.Gen_alum;
```

**updated**

use `Field()` to that display vertically data as your requirement

```
SELECT c.Nom_carre as Preparatory, sum(field(a.Gen_alum,'male')) as Male,sum(field(a.Gen_alum,'Female')) as Female
FROM alumno a
join carrera c on a.idCarrera=c.idCarrera
group by a.idCarrera;
```

here 'male' and 'female',change this with which you want to count from column

Comment: Is good but I put the gender vertically and do not put it horizontally

Comment: please show me your Gen_alum data

Comment: You're a genius, thank you, I worked perfectly! I apologize a little for my lack of congruence when I ask, I speak very little English: /

Comment: welcome dude.thanks for accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code.

```
SELECT c.Nom_carre AS Preparatory,
       count(a.Gen_alum) AS Gender
FROM alumno a,
     carrera c
WHERE a.idCarrera=c.idCarrera
GROUP BY a.Gen_alum
```

It helps you.

Comment: this will give an error: unknown column Gender in Group by clause

Answer (score 0):

Here you need to use `count` with group by

```
SELECT c.Nom_carre as Preparatory, count(a.Gen_alum) as Gender
FROM alumno a
JOIN carrera c ON a.idCarrera = c.idCarrera
GROUP BY a.Gen_alum
```

Comment: Is good but I put the gender vertically and do not put it horizontally

Comment: Share DB structure... do not understand what you mean by vertical or horizontal